# How to repeat the last part of a previous command?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using zsh with the [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) framework of Robby Russell. How can I create a shortcut or something to repeat the last part of a command?

For example, if I type:

```
mv something in/this/difficult/to/type/directory
```

Is there any way to easily get this: `in/this/difficult/to/type/directory`?

Answer (score 86):

Wether you are in *bash* or *zsh*, you can use the `!` operator to recover arguments of your previous command:

If we take: `echo a b c d` as an example

- `!$` - the last argument: *d*
- `!:*`- all the arguments: *a b c d* (can be shorten `!*`)
- `!:1` - the first argument: *a* (same as `!^`)
- `!:1-3` - arguments from first to third: *a b c*
- `!:2-$` - arguments from the second to the last one: *b c d*

This last point answer you question, you can take the last part of your command.

Note: `!:0` is the last command executed, here it would be *echo* in our example

The corresponding documentation can be found [on the gnu website](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Event-Designators), the whole context gives much more resources than this comment.

Comment: Just an additional comment here, at least with Oh my Zsh after typing the `!` argument you can expand it out hitting `tab`.

Comment: On your last line, did you mean `!:0`?

Comment: @babbata, nice catch ! I have fixed this in the body. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you add a link to canonical documentation about this please? Then the answer is perfect :)

Comment: @robrecord done, and there is much more to learn than my answer there :)

Answer (score 58):

I just tested and it seems you can do it the same way as in bash: `!$`.

Comment: pretty good, but I loved how in bash I could just press "ALT ."

Comment: alt-period? İ think I've heard that before, but it doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: @Kevin: Your meta key mapping may be screwy. What does `ALT+f` do? What about `ESC+.`?

Comment: Alt-f is some funny symbol, esc-. does the same symbol but inserts it at the cursor and doesn't advance.  Part of it may be that I'm using the US-intl keyboard.  I use vi-mode too, but I just checked and switching to emacs-mode doesn't fix it.

Comment: @Carlo Zsh has that same key binding in its default setup.

Comment: @Gilles, are you talking about `ALT+.`? at the moment, if I type `ALT+.` it outputs two dots and then goes up in the directory tree.

Comment: @Carlo `Alt+.` is in the default emacs keymap. If you don't have this binding, either your configuration overrides it (perhaps in oh-my-zsh) or you're using the vi keymap (which doesn't have this widget, `insert-last-word`, bound by default).

Comment: how do you prevent the command from repeating and just make it run? for example if you do `echo !$` and press enter, you see the command again, and you would have to press enter a second time to make it actually run. this is annoying.

Comment: @kentor I believe it's `setopt nohistverify`

Comment: @Kevin I used to use `ALT+.` (or I actually tended to use `ESC+.`) with zsh but I just moved to vi-mode prompt. The solution posted (thank you) works. Is there a way of getting a similar command working in zsh vi-mode?

Comment: For `ALT+.` use `bindkey '\e.' insert-last-word`.  Or, use `bindkey -M viins '\e.' insert-last-word` to apply just to vi (insert) mode.

Answer (score 22):

`!*` gives you *ALL* the arguments of the last command.

Example:

```
% echo hello world  
hello world

% echo !*  
(expands to)-> % echo hello world
hello world
```

Answer (score 16):

> add bindkey '\e.' insert-last-word to your .zshrc

- sp3ctum, in comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344699/zsh-how-to-repeat-the-last-part-of-a-previous-command#comment23610438_9236020)

Answer (score 15):

`<esc>.` also works out of the box with `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh`.

Comment: and this way you get to see the argunent before running it!

Answer (score 14):

`!$` gives you the last parameter of the previous command.

Example:

```
$ echo hello world
hello world
$ echo !$
echo world
world
```

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this too - I've always used `Alt.` for insert-last-word in bash.  Found where oh-my-zsh overrides this.

In lib/key-bindings.zsh, comment out this and it should work like in bash:

`bindkey -s '\e.' "..\n"`

Comment: Or add `bindkey '\e.' insert-last-word` to your .zshrc.

Comment: @sp3ctum your comment is the best answer IMO

Comment: I realise it's been ages, but @sp3ctum solution seems to be the only one working for me. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: did not work for me, I am using mac book pro 2017

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on @Charles Gueunet answer;

- `!!` - repeats the entire last command

This is useful if you forgot to add `sudo` to the start of the command.  Trivial example:

```
$ cat /root/file
Permission denied
$ sudo !!
here's the conent
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get here looking for **pasting last word from last command** on an **zsh** interactive shell, maybe this is your answer.

There is a default shortcut already configured in any zsh (or maybe if you have installed oh-my-zsh, i'm not really sure).
To check if you have this shortcut installed, search in bind keys for *insert-last-word*

```
$ bindkey -L | grep insert

...
bindkey "^[." insert-last-word
bindkey "^[_" insert-last-word
...
```

When using this keyboard shortcut, you can paste last word used in last command.
Example:

```
$   echo a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
...

$ 
[use shortcut]
$ g
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to reference the last argument of a command is with `$_`

```bash
mkdir 'a_new_directory'
cd $_
```

The above code will move you into the directory you just created.

`$_` can also do other things. Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280453/understand-the-meaning-of